# unable to render table with all results by default, then, only what is selected with selectoptions for re-render

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am re-asking this question, because it wouldn't let me put the code in a comment.

I am trying to have all results from a small table come up on page load, then, after one of the selectoptions is selected, the table changes to only the results matching those selected.

That 2nd part works, but, it only works because I have just set of an onchange event on the selectoptions list, how do I render the entire table by default on page load first.  I tried an outer outputPanel, that didn't work, but, I may have done something wrong.  I had to change some variable names, but, here is the code:

```
<apex:page standardController=" Sport__c" recordsetvar="sports" extensions="MenuController">
  <apex:form >
    <apex:PageBlock >
    <apex:pageblockSection >
       <apex:outputLabel > Sports Type : </apex:outputLabel>

    <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!selectedSport}">
      <apex:selectOptions value="{!SportsList }"/>
      <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!displayType}" reRender="sports_type"/>
    </apex:selectList> <br/>
    </apex:pageblockSection>
        <apex:outputPanel id="sports_type" >
    <apex:pageblocksection >
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!sports}" var="s">
        <apex:column value="{!s.Name}" title="Sport"/>
        <apex:column value="{!s.SportsType__c}" title="Type"/>
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
      </apex:pageblocksection>
      </apex:outputPanel>
      </apex:outputPanel>
      </apex:PageBlock>
      </apex:form>

</apex:page>

public with sharing class MenuController {
 public List<SelectOption> sportsList {get;set;}
 public String selectedSport {get;set;}
 public List<Sport__c> sports {get;set;}
    public MenuController(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {

      sportsList = new List<SelectOption>();
      sportsList.add(new SelectOption('All','All')); 
      sportsList.add(new SelectOption('Football','Football'));      
      sportsList.add(new SelectOption('Soccer','Soccer'));      
      sportsList.add(new SelectOption('Baseball','Baseball'));      

    }
  public PageReference displayType()  
  {
    if (selectedSport == 'Baseball') {
      sports  = [select  SportsType__c, name   from Sport__c WHERE SportsType__c = 'Baseball'];
    }
    else if (selectedSport == 'Football') {
      sports  = [select SportsType__c, name from Sport__c WHERE SportsType__c = 'Football'];
    }
    else if (selectedSport == 'Soccer') {
      sports  = [select SportsType__c, name  from Sport__c WHERE SportsType__c = 'Soccer'];
    }
   else {
   sports = [select SportsType__c, name from Sport__c];     
   }
    return null;
  }

}
```

Comment: There is an <apex:/outputPanel> tag left in the VisualForce markup above, I forgot to take that out, that was part of the outer outputPanel attempt, please ignore that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructor, you need to call the query function if you want to load the data when the page initially renders:

```
public with sharing class MenuController {
 public List<SelectOption> sportsList {get;set;}
 public String selectedSport {get;set;}
 public List<Sport__c> sports {get;set;}
    public MenuController(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
      sportsList = new List<SelectOption>();
      sportsList.add(new SelectOption('All','All')); 
      sportsList.add(new SelectOption('Football','Football'));      
      sportsList.add(new SelectOption('Soccer','Soccer'));      
      sportsList.add(new SelectOption('Baseball','Baseball'));      
      // ADDED THIS CODE
      displayType();
    }
  public PageReference displayType()  
  {
    if (selectedSport == 'Baseball') {
      sports  = [select  SportsType__c, name   from Sport__c WHERE SportsType__c = 'Baseball'];
    }
    else if (selectedSport == 'Football') {
      sports  = [select SportsType__c, name from Sport__c WHERE SportsType__c = 'Football'];
    }
    else if (selectedSport == 'Soccer') {
      sports  = [select SportsType__c, name  from Sport__c WHERE SportsType__c = 'Soccer'];
    }
   else {
   sports = [select SportsType__c, name from Sport__c];     
   }
    return null;
  }

}
```

As an aside, you really could clean up your displayType function:

```
public void displayType() {
    if(String.isNotBlank(selectedSport)) {
        sports = [SELECT SportsType__c, Name FROM Sport__c WHERE SportsType__c = :selectedSport];
    } else {
        sports = [SELECT SportsType__c, Name FROM Sport__c];
    }
}
```

To avoid having this query try to query "all" as a sport type, set the value to '' instead:

```
  sportsList = new List<SelectOption>();
  sportsList.add(new SelectOption('','All')); // No value selected
  sportsList.add(new SelectOption('Football','Football'));      
  sportsList.add(new SelectOption('Soccer','Soccer'));      
  sportsList.add(new SelectOption('Baseball','Baseball'));
```

Comment: Thank you so kindly.  I knew I was missing something.  That worked, and I really appreciate your cleaning up my code.